# Keyboard shortcut for Google Translate's 'Swap languages' button

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-translate, translation

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut for the **Swap languages** button [image: Swap languages button] in Google Translate.

[image: Google translate page showing English text translated to Spanish then swapping the languages using the]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily swap languages using:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>     - Windows
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>   - MacOS

Comment: Cmd ⌘+Shift+S for MacOS doesn't work in Safari due to its "Save as" shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that Google Translate doesn't have keyboard shortcuts, there isn't nothing on the UI and on the official help.

There are a couple of Chrome extensions that claims to add shortcuts to Google Translate but I didn't tried them.

- [Keyboard Shortcuts for Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts-for-go/akjhnbnjanndggbcegmdggfjjclohjpo?hl=en)
- [Google Translate Keyboard Shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate-keyboard/oppadelfinecikcbggmjjicoandngpba?hl=en)